# JSONObject with List to String to JsonNode

Tags: java, jackson, json

I convert JSONObject in string for parse it in JsonNode with jackson but i have a List in my JSONObject and when i parse it with a ObjectMapper i get this :

```
["{Property1 : value1, Property2 : value2}"]
```

And i can't call `myJsonNodeObject.get(i).get("Property1")` this is my problem.

I have tried to cast my List in JSONArray in my JSONObject but don't work.

```
resultAsJSONObject = new JSONObject();
resultAsJSONObject.put("Label", getMetricStatisticsResult.getLabel());
resultAsJSONObject.put("Datapoints", getMetricStatisticsResult.getDatapoints());
resultAsJSONObject.put("fromDate", fromDate.getTimeInMillis());
resultAsJSONObject.put("toDate", toDate.getTimeInMillis());
resultAsJSONObject.put("error", "");
resultAsString = resultAsJSONObject.toString();

mapper.readValue(resultAsString, MetricsData.class);
```

Comment: Can you please share your `MetricsData` bean and how you use it?

Comment: Why ? You don't need it. The problem is the List in JSONObject (getMetricsStatisticsResult.getDatapoints() return the List), it is convert to String with this format ["{Property1 : value1, Property2 : value2}"] but it's wrong i need this format : [{"Property1" : "value1", "Property2" : "value2"}"].

Comment: I wonder, why are you using JSONObject ? Can you just drop it?

Comment: Can i do this otherwise ? I use JSONObject because i just know this solution. What do you want i drop ?

Comment: So i have add <code>resultAsString = resultAsString.replace("\"[", "[");
   resultAsString = resultAsString.replace("]\"", "]");
   resultAsString = resultAsString.replace("\\\"", "\""); </code> ; but i think it's bad solution.

Comment: @Florian why don't just use Jackson for mapping Java object and JSON: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind#use-it

Comment: @Alexey I don't understand, i use Jackson for mapping this JSON. I get a JSON from CloudWatch Logs but he miss properties so i add them with a JSONObject and one property from CloudWatch Logs is Datapoints and i need to put it in my JSONObject for give a stringAsJSON with good properties for mapping.

Comment: There's a [jackson-datatype-json-org](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-json-org) module that will probably help you out

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you have a JSON string which you just want to change. Then you can use Jackson to parse it as a `ObjecNode` and then modify it. Here is an example:

```
public class JacksonModifyJson {

    static final String JSON = "{\"name\":\"Bob\", \"age\":13}";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        final ObjectNode jsonNode = mapper.readValue(JSON, ObjectNode.class);
        jsonNode.put("url", "example.com");
        System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(jsonNode));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{"name":"Bob","age":13,"url":"example.com"}
```

Answer (score 0):

THis method is really easy and works too

try {

```
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(THESTRINGHERE);
    String[] names = JSONObject.getNames(jsonObject);
    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.toJSONArray(new JSONArray(names));

    ArrayList<String> listdata = new ArrayList<String>();     
    JSONArray jArray = (JSONArray)jsonArray; 
    if (jArray != null) { 
       for (int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){ 
        listdata.add(jArray.get(i).toString());
       } 
    } 
//  System.out.println(listdata);



} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: This gives an error in `new JsonObject (The string here)` that cannot convert string into System.Collection.Generic.IEnumerable.